# Android SupportLib SwitchCompat View showing patches(Bounds)

Tags: android, android-studio

here is the cropped screenshot of my app.(Just focus the switchCompat Buttons). It was working properly till today when i tried to use **Android version 24** and **support lib version 24** , it all messed up.
even when i revert back to **API 23**, its showing the same.

I tried **invalidate cache and restart Android Studio**.
**AndroidStudio Version 2.1.2 / 2.2.0(preview3)**.

Still not showing properly.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move back to gradle plugin 2.1.2 from the alpha/beta versions. For Example:

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
```

In your root build.gradle file.